# What is the initrd.img.old file?

Tags: boot, kernel

When I run

> $ ls /

I get back:

bin    dev   initrd.img      lib64       mnt   root  snap      sys  var
boot   etc   **initrd.img.old**  lost+found  opt   run   srv       tmp  vmlinuz
cdrom  home  lib             media       proc  sbin  swapfile  usr  **vmlinuz.old**

I'm coming from using Windows a long time and usually I delete old image files. Is this normal in Linux, I'm trying to understand. Do I leave them be or can they/should the be removed?

Comment: You haven't provide OS/release details, but initrd means initial.ramdisk, the old one is used to boot an older kernel easily IF you have problems with upgrades/changes-to-your-latest kernel, so in theory it's not used, but it's there should you have problems. It's a link to the most-recent-but-old kernel (likewise to vmlinuz which is the kernel itself; v&z are old legacy posix/unix markers.. for virtual.mem & compressed)

Comment: If you're never going to have a problem, or never going to reboot; yes they can be deleted. But if you can't guarantee either, I'd suggest leaving them (they are handy if problems occur to bypass the problem & get your system booted!)  *Clarification: Your system will boot fine if they are removed; but if you have problems with latest kernel & need the older one.. that's when used.  If removed they'll likely re-appear on next kernel upgrade anyway*

Comment: Thanks for such a prompt detailed and helpful response! OS is Ubuntu 18.04. I will just leave them then. I'm sure they don't take much more than a couple hundred MB of ssd space anyway. I was just curious and after trying to remove the oldest kernel using `$ sudo apt-get purge \\old kernel verison pkg here\\` the files were still showing up in directory tree

Comment: If you `stat /initrd.img.old` you'll likely find it's a *symbolic link* (somewhat like shortcuts in windows; posix have multiple types of links) thus uses **no** disk space at all, it's just a entry in the file system that points to your prior kernel.